# How to call javascript function on keyup event for asp:TextBox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, events, client-side

How to call javascript function on keyup event for asp.net's TextBox control? I am trying something like this, but it is not working.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_userid" runat="server"  onkeyup="GetRes();"></asp:TextBox>
```

**UPDATE**

there is a update alert is working but breakpoints in java function is not working.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the line of code you have above. Are you getting any error? Have you defined your GetRes() function properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Test this solution:*

Add this code to your **page load**:

```
txt_userid.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "GetRes();");
```

I don't say this is best way possible, but it works.

**UPDATE:**

Complete sample:

ASPX:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_userid" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txt_userid.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "alert('hi');");
        }
```

Works perfectly. Tested it in IE, Chrome, FireFox.

Comment: onkeyup is the event that is used to handle it. Why do you say it is not working? Have you tried showing an `alert` ?

Comment: @Ranhiru Cooray: there is a update alert is working but breakpoints in java function is not working.

Comment: Do you want to handle the onkeyup event, client side using JavaScript OR in the server side using C#/VB.NET code? I know that you have specified client-side as a tag, but what break point do you expect in  JavaScript to work?

Comment: @jams: Updated my post. check it out. The sample I included works.

Answer (score 3):

it is very simple:

```
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "hello();");
```

in asp.cs code file.

then in aspx source file use javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hello() {

    alert("hi")

    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#<%=TextBox1%>').keyup(function () {
    updateDateKey($(this).val());
  });
});
```