# Passing a textbox value to javascript on key up function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Here i have passed the text control to the java script function but i just want to pass the value of the text box to the java script function instead on onkeyup.

```
function Changed(textControl) {
    var _txtEmpName = document.getElementById('<%=txtEmpName.ClientID%>');

    var _EnteredString = _txtEmpName.value;

<asp:TextBox
        ID="txtEmpName" runat="server" onkeyup="javascript: Changed( this );"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: document.getElementById('<%=txtEmpName.ClientID%>').value ?

Comment: See this url it's working nice for me...

[How to call javascript function on keyup event for asp:TextBox][1]

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607313/how-to-call-javascript-function-on-keyup-event-for-asptextbox

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pass the value instead, simply do:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpName" runat="server" 
 onkeyup="javascript: Changed( this.value );"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understand, but if you want to pass the value you should use `this.value` instead of just `this`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpName" runat="server" onkeyup="Changed(this.value)">
</asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use onblur instead of onkeyup?  You will be calling that function with every keystroke, is that something you really want to do?